# is it possible to have a public blob in an a private azure storage container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

is it possible to  have a public blob in an a private azure storage container

Currently I have an azure function that returns timestamped sas token fo read and write access to documents.

I now have a requirement for users to upload thumbnails that will be displayed on the website.

These can be public but I'd rather not create a private container for the images.

Is it possible to have public blobs in a private container.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer to your question is No. You can't have a publicly available blob in a private blob container. The ACL (Private, Blob or Public) is defined at the blob container level and all blobs in that container have that ACL.

You could create a container with `Public` or `Blob` ACL and have the users upload images there. For uploading, the requests would need to be authorized (using Shared Key, SAS or Token credentials) but the blobs can be displayed without any need for authorization.